# Delivering unknown recipients mail to specified mailbox

Tags: email, postfix

I`m developing a mailing list system and wanted to test it against big list of recipients.
Is there a way configuring postfix to accept any recipients address within some test domain and deliver it to a single specified user mailbox?  No other users/mailbox required.
System will be testing-purpose only and accessible only from local network.

If it cant be done in postfix, is there any other possibilities using other mail server software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a catch all email account. I am guessing you are using virtual domains on your Postfix installation. In your virtual alias table you just have to define:

```
some_user@example.com     some_user
@example.com              some_user
```

And all mail that comes to @example.com domain will be saved in the some_user@example.com account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to create a `canonical` lookup table.  See the `canonical` manpage.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier way in main.cf:

luser_relay= catchall@dummy-domain.com

local_recipient_maps =